# Стоит ли закрывать соединение с БД?

Tags: php, mysql

Стоит ли в пхп-коде после каждого запроса к mysql закрывать соединение с БД, если учесть, что соединение и так закрывается по завершению работы скрипта?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте вспомним старый добрый **php.net** : по окончанию работы сценария(конец кода/превышение лимита времени) автоматически будет освобождена память, занимаемая сценарием и закрыты все соединения **MySQL** кроме тех, которые были открыты через **mysql_pconnect**(если не ошибаюсь). После каждого запроса закрывать соединение не нужно, т.к. уходит очень много времени на повторное подключение, да и в случае ненадобности тоже трогать не нужно, ведь **PHP** самостоятельно закроет простое соединение по завершению сценария. Есть смысл очищать память от результатов запросов с помощью **mysql_free_result**.

Comment: Можно пул подключений использовать.

Answer (score 0):

После каждого запроса этого делать не надо, так как после первого запроса следующие выполнятся не будут. Достаточно закрывать соединение после выполнения скрипта.
Заодно прочитайте это:
http://php.net/manual/ru/features.persistent-connections.php

Comment: @admin, спасибо за ответ, на ваши слова "Достаточно закрывать соединение после выполнения скрипта" -  мне когда-то на Хэшкоде объясняли, что соединение само закрывается по завершении работы скрипта.