# В чем проблема поиска php-mysql, виснет сайт

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, mysqli

Написал поиск для сайта,
на языке php - бд mySql,
сам являюсь фронтенд девелопером,
всё работает, но зависает сильно, думаю проблема во множественных запросах в базу, или может надо как то закрывать сессию?

```
`$link = mysqli_connect('localhost',$user,$psswd,'$local_db');
 $rows2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($link,'SELECT `title` FROM 
 `tbl_product` WHERE `product_id` = '.$i));
 $rows3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($link,'SELECT `vendor_code` FROM 
 `tbl_product` WHERE `product_id` = '.$i));
 $rows4 = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($link,'SELECT `seo_keywords` FROM 
 `tbl_product` WHERE `product_id` = '.$i));
 $rows5 = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($link,'SELECT `alias` FROM 
 `tbl_product` WHERE `product_id` = '.$i));
 $rows6 = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($link,'SELECT `product_id` FROM 
 `tbl_product` WHERE `product_id` = '.$i));
 $rows7 = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($link,'SELECT `is_public` FROM 
 `tbl_product` WHERE `product_id` = '.$i));`
```

А также еще одна возможная причина, что фото c ценой приходиться парсить, использую, jquery Ajax и phpQuery, но товаров много.

```
`<script>
$( '.product_photo' ).each(function() {
var product_index = $(this).attr('photo-index');
var url = $(this).attr('photo-url');
//
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: '/prokladka/search/index.php',
data: 'class='+product_index+'&url='+url,
success: function(data){
  $('.results').append(data);
}
});
//
});
</script>`
```

Файл обработчик Ajax:

```
`// incoming vars
 $url = $_POST['url'];
$class = $_POST['class'];
// incoming vars
//
// including lib
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/prokladka/lib/phpquery-master/phpQuery/phpQuery.php');
// including lib
//
// lets start parsing
$page = file_get_contents($url);
$document = phpQuery::newDocument($page);
//
$img = $document->find('.product-album img')->attr('src');
$price = $document->find('.product-single .price')->html();
$price = trim(preg_replace('~\s+~s', ' ', $price)); 
//
echo "
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.product_photo_$class').attr('src','$img');
            $('.product_price_$class').html('".$price."');
        });
    </script>
";
// lets start parsing`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> mysqli_close ( mysqli $link )

- закрывает открытое соединение с базой данных.
  И все данные можно вместить в один запрос

  $rows2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($link,'
  SELECT `title`,`vendor_code`,`seo_keywords`, `alias`, `product_id`,`is_public` FROM `tbl_product` 
  WHERE `product_id` = '.$i));

А потом получить поля как удобно. В таблице, как я понимаю, это вообще будет одна строка? Тогда можно вообще упростить до

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `tbl_product` 
WHERE `product_id` = '.$i
```

Comment: $rows2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($link,'SELECT * FROM `tbl_product` WHERE `product_id` = ' .$i; и достовать через $rows2['нужный селектор']?

Comment: да. к примеру циклом. А дальше располагай как хочешь

while   (($result = $rows2->fetch_assoc())!=false):        
?>
<option value="<? print_r($result['WORK_DEPARTMENT']); ?>"> 
<? print_r($result['WORK_DEPARTMENT']);?></option> <?       
 endwhile;

Comment: mysqli_close ( mysqli $link ); - если не закрывать запросы mysql, то чем это чревата? И где закрыть его, сразу после  
$rows2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($link,'SELECT * FROM tbl_product WHERE product_id = ' .$i; ? или после вывода while?

Comment: Закрывать не обязательно. Он автоматически закроется по завершения выполнения php 
Почитай тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/197338/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%91%D0%94
и тут 
http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.close.php

Comment: Есть ещё советы по оптимизации кода?

Comment: Если сделал так как выше писал, то оптимизировать нечего в принципе. 
Настраивайте сам mysql на сервере